# Trailing if after dot all values are zeros in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove 0s after dot

I'm using SQL with Laravel, in database the prices are stored using decimal(10,3) [I need 3 decimals].

From database I'm getting

400.000 
451.500 
1.522 
20.000 
300.210
143.100

I've tried to do parseFloat and toFixed(3), but it's not working how I'm expecting.

I expect the output to be:

400
451.500
1.522
20
300.210
143.100

The values are not from an array. I'm getting the value from an AJAX response. I'm clicking on a button and I'm getting 400.000, clicking again.. I'm getting in response 451.500, etc.

Comment: Are the numbers in an array or assigned to individual variables?

Comment: Individual variables. I'm getting the value from a response

Comment: What have you tried so far? Let's see your [mcve].

Comment: So each number is inside their own respective JavaScript variable? Are the variable names sequential?

Comment: Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xepq187t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Array#filter and String#replace. Works by matching only 0's after the dot.

`/\.0+$/` is simple regex. It can be broken down into a few different parts. The outer `/`s (slashes) indicate that whatever within it is the regex.

The important part is actually, `\.0+$`. By default, `.` will match any character, but in this scenario we just want to find the numbers that contain a dot. So we `escape` it by using `\.`.

Once, we have the numbers that contain a dot, we need to see if they contain one or more 0s and only 0s.

`0+` will match at least one or more 0s.

`$` ensures that the number ends in a 0.

**tldr;** Essentially. `\.0+$` will match anything that contains a `.` and has at least one 0 trailing and ends in a 0.

```js
const data = ['123.001','400.000', '451.500', '1.520', '20.000', '300.210', '143.100']

const res = data.map(n=>{
  return n.replace(/\.0+$/, "");
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This did the trick: n.replace(/\.0+/, "");  i wanted for variable.  Can you help me a little and explain how it's working..? I'm a little confused

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: More specific...I don't understand the part with /\.0+/

Comment: This will fail for inputs like `123.001`

Comment: If will return 123.001 it's ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity sake, I turned your values into an array, however how you  iterate over the values is up to you; here's the concept:

```js
let arr = [400.000, 451.500, 1.522, 20.000, 300.210, 143.100]

    for(let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        if(arr[x] % 1 == 0) {
            arr[x] = arr[x].toFixed(0);
        }
        else {
            arr[x] = arr[x].toFixed(3);
        }
        console.log(arr[x])
    }
```

What this does is checks the value to see if it is divisible by 1 and returns without any decimal places, otherwise, it lets it round to 3 decimal places.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to check if the all the digits after `\.` are zero or not.

If zero than replace with empty string else keep as it is.

```js
const data = ['400.000', '451.500', '1.520', '20.000', '300.210', '143.001']

const res = data.map(n=>{
  return n.replace(/\.0+$/, "");
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var number = 1.2345678;
var result_number = round(number, 3);
console.log(result_number);
function round(value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
}
```

Try this, and it will solve your issue :)